# Transforming the results of a KStream windowed aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 1 minute windows for some events coming through one of my topics.  I am looking to take the results of that window, and transform it one more time in order to get my final results I want to push to a sink.  These are my DSL calls to accomplish up to my aggregate.

```
val sessionProcessorStream = builder.stream("collector-prod", Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String, Serdes.String)) //[String,String]
  .filter((_, value) => filterRequest(value))
  .transform(valTransformer,"valTransformState") //[String,String]
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(SessionWindows.`with`(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))) //[Windowed[String],String]
  .aggregate(sessionInitializer,sessionAggregator,sessionMerger,sessionMaterialized) //[Windowed[String],SessionEvent]
  .toStream      
  .transform(sessionTransformer,"sessionTransformState") // [String,Long]
```

When I try to run this and process two events within the same window I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "9-fc11122f-0db3-401b-bdaa-2480eacb8e74-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: task [1_0] Failed to flush state store session-agg-store7
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:245)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:327)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:302)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:292)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks$2.apply(AssignedTasks.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.applyToRunningTasks(AssignedTasks.java:452)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit(AssignedTasks.java:381)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll(TaskManager.java:310)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:1018)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:835)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:857)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3079)
    at SessionEventDeserializer.deserialize(SessionEventDeserializer.scala:17)
    at SessionEventDeserializer.deserialize(SessionEventDeserializer.scala:8)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:158)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingSessionStore.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore.access$000(CachingSessionStore.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore$1.apply(CachingSessionStore.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:141)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingSessionStore.flush(CachingSessionStore.java:196)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredSessionStore.flush(MeteredSessionStore.java:165)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:242)
    ... 14 more
```

I'm not sure of the exact cause of the exception, however, I do think there is a problem that my key for the stream going into the last transform is a `Windowed[String]`.  I think and would expect it to be a normal `String`.

I tried to solve this by running a `.map` after the toStream

```
  .map { (_,v) => {
      new KeyValue[String,SessionEvent](v.name,v)
  }}
```

However I get a compile time error that I am unable to figure out.

```
Error:(106, 8) no type parameters for method map: (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String], _ >: SessionEvent, _ <: org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[_ <: KR, _ <: VR]])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream[KR,VR] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String],SessionEvent,org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[String,SessionEvent]])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String],SessionEvent,org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[String,SessionEvent]]
 required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String], _ >: SessionEvent, _ <: org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[_ <: ?KR, _ <: ?VR]]
      .map { (_,v) => {
Error:(106, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String],SessionEvent,org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[String,SessionEvent]]
 required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String], _ >: SessionEvent, _ <: org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[_ <: KR, _ <: VR]]
      .map { (_,v) => {
```

What is the correct way to transform the result of a windowed aggregate?  I would appreciate any help and would be happy to clarify further on any points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error originates from "flush", thus I doubt it's the transformer after the aggregation, but rather the aggregation itself. I assume that there is a bug in you `SessionEventDeserializer`, as it throws a `NullPointerException` -- do you handle `null` correctly? You deserializer must be able to handle `null` and return `null` for this case.